# WordPress - Show Posts based on multiple taxonomy terms

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

The code below is for a taxonomy template  (taxonomy-city.php), within each post I have two taxonomies City and Region.

I'm trying to show posts that share the same region as the city. eg if I'm on the London page I want to show other cities that have the Europe taxonomy term selected.

```
        <?php
            $today = date('Ymd');
            $term = $wp_query->queried_object;
            $getterm = $term->slug; 
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => '9',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',

                'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                      'taxonomy' => 'city',
                      'field' => 'slug',
                      'terms' => $getterm,
                      'include_children' => true,          
                      'operator' => 'IN'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'region',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => array( 'europe', 'asia-pacific', 'north-america' ),
                    )
                ),
                'meta_query' => array(
             array(
                'key'       => 'date',
                'compare'   => '>=',
                'value'     => $today,
            )
                ),  
            );
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually said what the problem is. However, if you want the search to be, eg "London" in "Europe", then your `relation` should be set to `AND`. Also, you should add `'operator' => 'IN'` to your region tax parameters. I know it's the default setting, but it doesn't hurt to explicitly declare it.

Comment: I'm trying to link the two so I can see other events in that region based on the city that I'm on. Each post with have a city and region selected in the dashboard. My query at the moment is displaying just the current city posts but I want to show the region.